# How can I read a table from a URL and keep it as a dataframe?

Tags: r, url, dataframe, read.table

I have problems with the function read.table. I want to read a table from an url, and keep it in R as a dataframe. The url is:
https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt

I have wrote this code:

```
library(RCurl)

a <- getURL('https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt')
b = read.table(a, sep="\t ", header = TRUE, nrows=3)

download.file("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt","/mnt/M/Ana/R/datos_treemap.txt",method = c("wget"))
```

But I can't keep the data as a dataframe, and it results in the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file...
No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to download the document as a txt, and keep it in mi PC. But the generate txt results in a vector instead of a table (all the results are in one unic row). The code I have wrote is:

```
download.file("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt","/mnt/M/Ana/R/datos_treemap.txt",method = c("wget"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(RCurl)
a <- getURL('https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt')
b <- read.table(text=a, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another solution using `rvest`instead of `RCurl`. I do not want to judge which package is "better", just wanted to show an additional option, although, in your simple case `rvest` seems to be more verbose and you need SelectorGadget to identify the desired node (please anybody correct me if I am wrong and the code can be shortened).

```
library(rvest)

table <- read_html("https://datanalytics.com/uploads/datos_treemap.txt") %>% 
         html_text("p") %>% 
         { read.table(text = ., header = T) }
```